# Как убрать затемнение текста при свойстве opacity?

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

```css
.price-building {
  background: url(../photo/vlcsnap-2018-09-10-13h28m31s589.png);
  background-position-x: -815px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.price-building:hover {
  ## Заголовок ##opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 1s;
}

.price-business {
  background: url(../photo/Business-People-Desk.jpg);
  background-position-x: -1500px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.price-business:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 1s;
}

.judge-expert {
  background: url(../photo/ph2ylsyy377100.jpg);
  background-position-x: -300px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.judge-expert:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dispute {
  background: url(../photo/corporate-alliances-that-get-results.jpg);
  background-position-x: -750px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dispute:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<section class="information mask">
  <div class="information-container">
    <div class="information-content_container price-building">
      <div class="information-inner">
        <div class="step-title">
          <p>
            оценка<br> недвижимости
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="information-content_container price-business">
      <div class="information-inner">
        <div class="step-title">
          <p>
            оценка<br> бизнеса
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="information-content_container dispute">
      <div class="information-inner">
        <div class="step-title">
          <p>
            оспаривание<br> кадастровой стоимости
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="information-content_container judge-expert">
      <div class="information-inner">
        <div class="step-title">
          <p>
            судебная<br> экспертиза
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: А верстки не будет?

Comment: @MishaSaidov сейчас попробую добавить

Comment: @MishaSaidov добавил, извиняюсь за неаккуратность. Впервые пользуюсь функцией "задать вопрос".

Comment: Ок, что значит `убрать затемнение текста`? Сейчас при наведении текст становится более прозрачным. Какого результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: @MishaSaidov я хочу чтобы текст оставался в блоке белым, как задано в стилях. Сейчас проблема состоит в том, что при наведении на блок затемняются все его компоненты. Мне нужно чтобы текст в блоке оставался белым независимо от наведения на блок. Нужно лишь затемнение background (где вставлена фотография). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрых времени суток, вот одна из возможных реализаций вашей задачи:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-block">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.image-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    &::before{
        content: '';
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    &:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

*Вот пример на Codepen: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/ebMbyv)*

Comment: если использовать before то z-index не нужен

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за замечание, Вы правы! Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: @meine Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @Grundy Большое спасибо!